# How can you play a .wmv file in Flutter web?

Tags: flutter, web, flutter-web, video-player, wmv

I am creating a video player that supports video from multiple formats and i cant play video from .wmv format.

So when i try to run .wmv file in different video player packages, formats like(mp4,3gp..) supports except .wmv file and it says "Track cant be played". Any idea on how to do is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The .wmv format is not supported on a lot of browsers. You'll probably have to just scrap the idea of including that format.